# JBoss6 Classloading Jar Search Order

Tags: classloader, jboss6.x

We are migrating a web application from JBoss 4.2.3 to JBoss 6.  The application needs to control the order in which jars are searched for classes during classloading.  This was achieved in JBoss 4.2.3 by hacking EARDeployer class in jboss.jar to add jars to the DeploymentInfo object in a specific order.

Is there a way to achieve the same result in JBoss 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ales Justin over at JBoss was able to help me through this.  Our conversation can be found here: [Link](http://community.jboss.org/message/593922#593922)